# How to restore auto_ptr in Visual Studio C++17

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++17, deprecated

This blog page mentions that Visual Studio removes some std features:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/08/c17-feature-removals-and-deprecations/

I have a project that consumes some C++ libraries that now use C++17 features. The project also consumes a third party library websocketpp (https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) that still uses some now removed features. eg auto_ptr and binary_function. I'm getting compiler errors that they are not a member of 'std'.

The blog above mentions that removed features can be restored using a fine grain control. I'm thinking I could use that to get this project to compile for now. Longer term I will see about upgrading websocketpp to C++17 or replacing it with something else.

But, what is the magic to restore features? Is there something I need to #define? If so, what?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In VS2017 v15.5 it is conditionally excluded, based on the project's /std:c++17 setting.  You can force it to be included by forcing the underlying macro value.  Two basic ways to do this:

1. Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions and add `_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC=1`.  Do so for all configurations and platforms.
2. If you use a precompiled header then you probably favor defining the macro there.  Before any #includes, insert `#define _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC 1`.

Beware of the "ETC", you'll also slurp the deprecated random_shuffle() and unary_function<>.  Predicting the future is difficult, but this is probably going to work for a while to come.

Comment: I tried to use _HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC in VS2019, but it did not help. I switched to using unique_ptr.

Comment: No, it is still used in VS2019's version of `<memory>` to define auto_ptr.

Comment: Hans - Yes, my bad. Including <memory> was necessary. I could not edit my previous comment, so posted this as a separate one.