# Switching from c++17 to c++14 in Qt-creator project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am upgrading my project(s) to Qt 6.4.1 with Qt Creator 9.0.1.

When building the projects (and running QMake), I received multiple errors, caused by the MSVC2019 compiler using C++17, instead of the preferred C++14 compiler. So I want to to force Qt to compile the project using C++14.

I have tried forcing C++14 in two ways, using both `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std:c++14` and `CONFIG += c++14`.
This does indeed add the `-std:c++14` flag during compilation, but there is also still a `-std:c++17` flag. The compiler mentions `cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/std:c++14' with '/std:c++17'`.

I cannot find any location in the project-files or settings that may add this c++17 option.
I have tried removing the option using `CONFIG -= c++17` and `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -std:c++17`, but this does not work.

What setting may cause the compilation to use C++17 and how can I disable/change it to using C++14?

Comment: What *are* the errors you get? Perhaps it's easier to simply fix those errors to make your program build with both C++14 and C++17?

Comment: Unfortunately, the errors are in in third party header files (auto_ptr). For me, this route is currently not possible.

Comment: you could just disable the removal of deprecated features: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48882439/how-to-restore-auto-ptr-in-visual-studio-c17 otherwise I'd guess you might need to modify the QT mkspecs (if Qt 6 even works without c++17?, sounds like it doesn't `With Qt 6 we now require a C++17 compatible compiler enabling the use more modern C++ language constructs when developing Qt and also allows for integration points on the API side.` https://www.qt.io/blog/qt-6.0-released)

Comment: Indeed, disabling the removal of deprecated features fixes all issues for auto_ptr. Unfortunately, the third party library also contains dynamic exception specifications. These errors are not resolved by defining `_HAS_AUTO_PTR_ETC 1`.